# Error al migrar mi servicio REST de Tomcat a WebLogic12

Tags: rest, tomcat, weblogic, jersey

Mi servicio funciona bien en Tomcat pero al migrarlo a WebLogic me genera un error, ya que veo que usa la libreria or.glassfish de Weblogic e ignora CXF de Tomcat.

El error es el siguiente:

```
WARNING: No injection source found for a parameter of type public mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.respuestaBusqueda mx.com.qualitas.menu.web.servicio.MenuServicioRest.busqueda(mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.peticionBusqueda) at index 0.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
WARNING: Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.
> 
<8/10/2020 12:20:13,475 PM CDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "JAX-RS/Jersey#1" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "MenuE_web".
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReader(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyReader.setDelegatingReaders(java.util.List)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriter(javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List<javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<T>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.CachingMessageBodyWriter.setDelegatingWriters(java.util.List)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type T from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(T) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider.setObject(java.lang.Object)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassWriters(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassBuilders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomClassReaders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AbstractAtomElementBuilder<?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomBuilders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementReader<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomReaders(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomElementWriter<?, ?>>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.atom.AtomPojoProvider.setAtomWriters(java.util.Map)', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.lang.Class<?>[] from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class<?>[]) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractJAXBProvider.setExtraClass(java.lang.Class[])', [WARNING] Parameter 1 of type java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String> from public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Enum<?>, java.lang.String>) is not resolvable to a concrete type.; source='public void org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider.setEnumResources(java.util.Map)', [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.respuestaBusqueda mx.com.qualitas.menu.web.servicio.MenuServicioRest.busqueda(mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.peticionBusqueda) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class mx.com.qualitas.menu.web.servicio.MenuServicioRest, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@22921f9]}, definitionMethod=public mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.respuestaBusqueda mx.com.qualitas.menu.web.servicio.MenuServicioRest.busqueda(mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.peticionBusqueda), parameters=[Parameter [type=class mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.peticionBusqueda, source=, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class mx.com.qualitas.menu.busqueda.model.respuestaBusqueda}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Llevo varios dias con este problema. por favor si alguien puede aportarme información.

Comment: agrega el error completo por favor

Comment: Actualicé mi pregunta con los errores. Agradeceria pudieras ayudarme un poquito por favor

Comment: La última vez que lidié con esto, tenía que ver con varias clases que Weblogic incluye y usa por prelación en el classpath. Así pues, hay que añadir excepciones para que no cargue ciertas librerías/paquetes/clases de las versiones incluidas (que son viejas, forks de Oracle/ etc)